# Can I use a decompiled method?

Tags: java, aes, apk

I'm new to Java, in fact I know next to nothing. I've been interested in the type of data an android app is holding on me. So, I can see within an XML file this app has created strings which appear to to be encrypted using AES128-CBC.

So I've decompiled their .apk file and looking through their source I can see a method they call to decode stuff (DecodeMe). Can I pass my encrypted strings through this using their method and it will decrypt it?

Sorry, I'm not too clued up on this.

Comment: I guess and hope the answer would be that no, you can't decrypt it :). Can you post the relevant decompiled `DecodeMe` method?

Comment: Please do *not* post the code of an Android application you've decompiled. That is likely to be illegal. In fact, I've flagged this question for removal.

Comment: @yair, whether or not text can be decrypted depends on the encryption method used, two-way or one-way. In this case, AES128-CBC is used and to be honest I have no idea whether that is one-way or two-way encryption.

Comment: Duncan, I think it's a very good question and if it's the case that these so called encryption methods can easily be reversed by decompiling apps then I think it's something should be aware of before entering their personal details. I'm not stating the app I am decompiling. Just to note, this doesn't even go against their ToS.

Comment: @munyul AES128-CBC is symmetric. AES is a symmetric block algorithm and chained-block-cipher doesn't change this property. iYugshell: I don't condone information theft but you're likely to try passing the strings through the method *at your own risk*. Please note that I, and/or Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange will *not* be responsible for any legal consequences you may encounter.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a process that may be unethical or illegal under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience with Android development at all, I can only comment from the Java side of things.

If you have been able to decompile the program, you should be able to use the code as you like - so, assuming that DecodeMe really does what it's name implies, then yes it should decode the text.

Add the decompiled code to a new project in your favourite Java IDE, create your own main(...) class/method and try calling the DecodeMe - it *shouldn't* take too much effort to set up and test.

EDIT: Yes, you can use a decompiled method - you simply need to make sure all methods/classes it uses are also available.

Comment: Thanks for your input, if what you say is true thats quite scary to think how this venerable this app is. Thanks! :)

Comment: The program is not really _vulnerable_ as the encrypted text still requires the correct password to be decrypted. As for Java programs being decompilable, yes that is an issue which a lot of larger software developers don't like as it becomes too easy for others to _steal_ their code.

Answer (score -2):

That is a java method you just mined from the APK.

> private void doNothing() {}

Whoa, this is another. You can use it.
Sorry, just some fun. :)
Yes, you can actually use it, but check if it uses some class that is also defined in the application. You have to mine all custom classes, too.

Comment: I find this answer confusing.

Comment: @DuncanJones If the mined method uses some custom class (returns or gets it as parameter, or uses in the method body somehow) that is also in the APK, he has to mine that as well and make available in the same context as where he tries to use the method. Or compilation with fail with unknown types.